# Can I bind a shortcut to quick fix a specific weak warning?

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

[image]

I'm trying to bind a shortcut key to a specific weak warning in GoLand.

I like declaring implicit struct literals.

Although I click on it in the gif there I have it now the option "Show quick fixes" binded to a shortcut but I still have to navigate to the Problems toolwindow, and select the warning.

Is there a way I can do it in one shortcut key? Just for this specific warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to work around it, or i guess what i've been doing was the work around coz what i should be doing is accessing the `show context actions` options from the editor now i just do that keybind and press on enter and it just goes. :)